# How to declare a function identifier

Tags: c++, function, identifier

If i have a sample code like this:

```
void func_1 {
.......
func_2;
}
func_2{
.......
}
```

I need to declare a function identifier for `func_2` so that the code could run how do i do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Do you want to run func_2() at the end of func_1()?  What problems are you having now?

Comment: I need to call func_2 from func_1 but the thing is that i wrote func_2 after func_1 so i have to write an identifer at the top , right??

Comment: This doesn't look like legal C or C++ -- functions have round brackets after their identifier. Declaration is `int f(double x);`, definition is `int f(double x) { return -1; }`. You can declare `func_2` before you define `func_1`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

If `func_2` won't call `func_1`, then you can just reorder them:

```
void func_2()
{
}

void func_1()
{
  // ...
  func_2();
}
```

If they both call each other, then you can declare like so:

```
void func2();
void func1()
{
  // ...
  func2();
}

void func2()
{
  // ...
  func1();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void func_2 ();

void func_1 ()
{
 ...
}

void func_2 ()
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: The declaration of `func_2` should be above the definition of `func_1`.

Comment: But technically it can go anywhere, but yes, it probably should.

Comment: the question states that func_2 is called from func_1 so the ordering is **not** optional.

Comment: Inside a class, functions can be in any order. Stand-alone functions, however, can only call functions that have already been defined (or have forward references defined).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that statement about it needing to be called from inside.